# uninitialized constant OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoGeometry

Tags: ruby, oracle, activerecord

I need to patch oracle enhanced adapter for some reasons.

In my oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb file, I need to get  OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoGeometry.new return value, but it returns uninitialized constant **OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoGeometry**.

But, if before executing OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoGeometry.new command, I execute OnlineGpsPoint.first command (OnlineGpsPoint contains an sdo_geometry column) and get one of the rows in the table, OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoGeometry will be initialized.

The problem is that I don't want hardcoded 'OnlineGpsPoint' in my program. I just need OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoGeometry value.

Is there a solution for the pain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ruby-oci8 finds an unknown object type, it automatically defines a ruby class under OCI8::Object. If you know the object type name, it is better to define the ruby class in advance as follows:

```
# Oracle object type name is *guessed* from the ruby class name.
#   SdoGeometry => SDO_GEOMETRY ==(public synonym)=> MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY
class SdoGeometry < OCI8::Object::Base
end
```

or

```
# Set Oracle object type name explicitly
class AnyClassName < OCI8::Object::Base
  set_typename('MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY')
end
```

If you want same name with the automatically generated class:

```
module OCI8::Object::Mdsys
  class SdoGeometry < OCI8::Object::Base
    set_typename('MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY')
  end
end
```

Comment: but I don't understand your third code. What's the difference with first code section?

Comment: It just defines SdoGeometry under OCI8::Object::Mdsys.

Comment: The first defines it at the toplevel namespace.